# python selenium screenshot captcha image

Tags: python, selenium

i want to take screenshot and crop only the captcha image, im write this code : http://pastebin.com/Hqau6kRD :

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#imagecpt")
loc  = elem.location
size = elem.size
left  = loc['x']
top   = loc['y']
width = size['width']
height = size['height']
box = (int(left), int(top), int(left+width), int(top+height))
screenshot = driver.get_screenshot_as_png()
img = Image.open(StringIO.StringIO(screenshot))
area = img.crop(box)
area.save('screenshot.png', 'PNG')
```

the image saved is complete black, where im wrong ?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I think this is not behaving as you expect: "StringIO.StringIO(screenshot)"

Comment: What is `Image`? Is it a module you installed via `pip`, or did it come with your Python installation? If it came with your Python install, which version are you using and where did you get it from? I suspect your problem is that your `Image` library probably doesn't handle png files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using the `Image` module from [`PIL`](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm) library.

Try getting the base64 value, decode it and then pass it as a parameter to the `open()` method.

```
...
screenshot = driver.get_screenshot_as_base64()
img = Image.open(StringIO.StringIO(base64.b64decode(screenshot))
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Yeah. For Python3 it will be like:

```
...
from io import BytesIO
...
screenshot = driver.get_screenshot_as_base64()
img = Image.open(BytesIO(base64.b64decode(screenshot))
...
```